# Why does sorting this list of dicts fail when I change the order of the keys?

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts I am sorting. Why does the first method pass but the second fails? The [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) don't address this (or I'm just missing something totally obvious).

```
listy = []
listy.append({'a':None,'b':'Fred'})
listy.append({'a':datetime.now().date(),'b':'Dave'})

listy.sort(key=lambda k:(k['b'],k['a'])) # o.k.
listy.sort(key=lambda k:(k['a'],k['b'])) # fails with "TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to NoneType"
```

Comment: Try `listy.append({'a':23, 'b':'Dave'})'` and you'll see the same error with the first sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case you are comparing the tuples

```
('Fred', None) < ('Dave', datetime.now().date())
```

Since the first element of each tuple is different, Python doesn't need to compare the second element at all to know which one is less than the other.

In the second case you are comparing `None` to a `date`. Python2 did allow mixed type comparisons (though not this specific case - see the comments), but it wasn't particularly useful and is more likely to cause strange bugs, so this ability was removed in Python3

Comment: Python 2 didn't allow this either. It allowed comparing many different types to each other that weren't particularly useful, but not _all_ of them, and `None < datetime.now().date()` will raise a `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to NoneType`. (In 3.x, this is handled by the general error case, with a slightly better error message: `TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.date() < NoneType()`.)

Answer (score 0):

It is comparing tuples element by element. It will only compare the second elements if the first ones are equal.  In other words, it would fail if both 'b' values were set to 'Dave'.

Comment: you are right but gnibbler beat you to it...upvoted you but will accept gnibbler